# Shopiy-API-Node - Get Smart Collections Metafields

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-api-node

I'm using the Shopify SDK '[Shopiy-API-Node](https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node/)' and wonder how to get metafields of a smart collections ?

The Shopify api says:

GET /admin/collections/#{id}/metafields.json

Also, from NodeJS I use :

```
shopify.metafield.list(
    { 
        metafield: { 
            owner_resource: 'COLLECTION', 
            owner_id: '4576719568993' 
        }
    }
);
```

But it returns a 404, while I'm sure there are Metafields datas, as the Shopify Api returns the Metafields if queried without the SDK.

Cheers
Alan

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work this way :

```
shopify.metafield.list(
    { 
        metafield: { 
            owner_resource: 'collections', 
            owner_id: '4576719568993' 
        }
    }
);
```

You have to use "collectionS".

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting an empty response because you are only entitled to get metafields your API key created. If you have not used your API key to attach a metafield to a collection, then [] is correct.

Comment: Hi, yes I do, i just did not displayed here all the code to stay focus on the call. Thanks for the help anyway. I'm afraid  the SDK does not provide the necessary functions to retrieve these datas.